# Adding/Displaying Custom fields in Shopify

Tags: shopify, user-accounts

We are building a shop on Shopify we are wanting to add custom fields to the "my account" page that a user views once they are logged in. Currently it shows their order history and they can add/edit their billing/shipping addresses.

I wanting to allow users to edit their email address and add other fields they can update.

I am also wanting this imputed information to be seen in the "customers" page in the Shopify dashboard for admin use or possibly on orders themselves.

We are currently using a 3rd party app but I need to get this information to appear in other places.

My question is, what is the best method, or easiest to add custom fields POST/GET in Shopify.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This will help you get started https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/communication/get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form - Also note that this a coding forum so these types of questions without any info of what you are trying/tried are going to be down-voted.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read over that. Thanks for the tip. I'll be sure to include what I've tried/trying next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your theme files to include the display of custom fields. If your custom fields are mostly informational you can create them [as a note](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/communication/get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form)

Unfortunately that appears to work for registration only. When I have had to do this sort of thing I've used an app that presents a form to the logged in customer via an app proxy and updates meta fields on the customer record.

Comment: We've been using customr, you just can't see the information within the actual Shopify customers dashboard. You have to use the app dashboard. I was trying to get around that. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Displaying the information is pretty easy. You just alter the customers/account.liquid template. It's updating the customer that requires some work.

Comment: @bknights.. I think Alissa is talking about showing extra information in the admin dashboard panel - `/admin/customes/<xyz>`

Comment: @AlissaIsenberg, if you are using a chrome/chromium based browser there is plugin which shows metafields across the admin dashboard where ever possible. Check out for the extension "ShopifyFD"

Comment: @Hymnz yes, I am wanting to display the information in the admin dashboard panel, customers. Instead of having to go through the 3rd party app we are using, Customr. I looked at the ShopifyFD extension, I'm just unsure how to utilize it. This is my first time working with Shopify and was only brought on this project a week ago. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AlissaIsenberg .. ShopifyFD accesses metafields on each object type that is suitable. Check - https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield. ShopifyFD's website has good enough guides on how to use the plugin - http://shopifyfd.com/